# Is there a good way to transfer a DNS Zone from a bind9 server to a new domain with the same name running on freeIPA? [zone to ldif]

Tags: bind, internal-dns, freeipa, ldif

I'm working within a company network that has DNS servers but did not have an actual Domain. After installing a FreeIPA server and setting up the domain (same name as the DNS zone in the bind9 DNS server) I'm struggling with a way to move the current zone to the FreeIPA server as the master and the old bind9 server as a slave.

I've configured the FreeIPA server to do zone transfers however I'm struggling with the formatting required to convert the bind zone file into an LDIF for import into the FreeIPA system. I've found some scripts online, however they are either severely outdated or - with regard to using pdns_zone2ldap give me errors with the named.conf file.

I feel like I am missing something obvious, however after days of trying to figure this out myself I'm hoping someone has done this before and can give me an idea of where to go next.

Edit: Adding more context

When using pdns_zone2ldap I'm getting the following error:

```
pdns_zone2ldap --named-conf=/etc/named.conf --zone-file=company.net.zone --zone-name=company.net --verbose=yes
Fatal error: Error in bind configuration '/etc/named.conf' on line 37: syntax error
```

The config file in question (/etc/named.conf) is found below:

```
/* WARNING: This config file is managed by IPA.
 *
 * DO NOT MODIFY! Any modification will be overwritten by upgrades.
 *
 *
 * - /etc/named/ipa-options-ext.conf (for options)
 * - /etc/named/ipa-logging-ext.conf (for logging options)
 * - /etc/named/ipa-ext.conf (all other settings)
 */

options {
        // Put files that named is allowed to write in the data/ directory:
        directory "/var/named"; // the default
        dump-file               "data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file         "data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file      "data/named_mem_stats.txt";

        tkey-gssapi-keytab "/etc/named.keytab";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        /* user customizations of options */
        include "/etc/named/ipa-options-ext.conf";

        /* crypto policy snippet on platforms with system-wide policy. */
        include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
};

/* If you want to enable debugging, eg. using the 'rndc trace' command,
 * By default, SELinux policy does not allow named to modify the /var/named directory,
 * so put the default debug log file in data/ :
 */
logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
                print-time yes;
        };
        include "/etc/named/ipa-logging-ext.conf";
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

/* user customization */
include "/etc/named/ipa-ext.conf";

dyndb "ipa" "/usr/lib64/bind/ldap.so" {
        uri "ldapi://%2fvar%2frun%2fslapd-company-NET.socket";
        base "cn=dns,dc=company,dc=net";
        server_id "servername.company.net";
        auth_method "sasl";
        sasl_mech "EXTERNAL";
        krb5_keytab "FILE:/etc/named.keytab";
};
```

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: pdns_zone2ldap --named-conf=/etc/named.conf --zone-file=company.net.zone --zone-name=company.net
Fatal error: Error in bind configuration '/etc/named.conf' on line 37: syntax error

Comment: Without seeing your zonefile we're probably not going to be able to help out.

Comment: Include your config files. [Edit] your question to add new information.

Comment: I added the config you asked for, I'll work on modifying the zone file for upload, I'll pretty much have to strip everything out of it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use PDNS convertor. It will not produce you a suitable LDIF file for FreeIPA because it has no knowledge of FreeIPA-specific LDAP schema.

Instead, look at https://github.com/freeipa/zone2dyndb-ldif. This tool knows how to produce FreeIPA-specific LDAP entries.